# how do i tell a uitableview which array to load depending on what the date is

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I am making an iPhone app which has a tableview. The tableview needs to display different information on different days of the year.

I can't seem to figure out how to tell the tableview which data to display.

For example a sports fixture will load different information depending on which week of the year it is.

Please help

Comment: based upon remodify datasource array . Keep your year/date array seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- List item

You can have an array of `NSDictionary` items and have a key 'date' that will store the event date. Somewhere in init you can filter your data source array using a `NSPredicate`. Something like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName: (NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle: (NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

    _eventsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"Christmas event", @"name",
                     [formatter dateFromString: @"2013-12-25"], @"date",
                     nil],
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"New Year event", @"name",
                     [formatter dateFromString: @"2014-01-01"], @"date",
                     nil],
                    nil];
    __block typeof(formatter) blockFormatter = formatter;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(NSDictionary *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSDate *date = [evaluatedObject objectForKey: @"date"];

        if ([date isEqualToDate: [blockFormatter dateFromString: @"2013-12-25"]])
            return YES;

        return NO;
    }];

    _dataSource = [_eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

    [formatter release];
}

return self;
```

}

You can modify the predicate to check if the date is in the current week, or whatever you need.

P.S. Don't forget to release `_eventsArray` in `dealloc`.